# Unable to get result in jpql query, my result query size is 0

Tags: mysql, spring, jpql

Unable to get result in jpql query, my result query size is 0,

```
     List<Exercise> prevexercise=  (List<Exercise>)em.createQuery("Select e from Exercise e where e.activity = '"+exercise.getActivity()+"' AND e.GOAL_ID = '"+goal.getId()+"'").getResultList();
```

I dont know what is wrong in above query  please help me with this i am new to this the error as below

un 04, 2015 5:16:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [fitTrackerServlet] in context with path [/FitnessTracker] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: GOAL_ID of: com.pluralsight.model.Exercise [Select e from com.pluralsight.model.Exercise e where e.activity = 'Run' AND e.GOAL_ID = '1']] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: GOAL_ID of: com.pluralsight.model.Exercise [Select e from com.pluralsight.model.Exercise e where e.activity = 'Run' AND e.GOAL_ID = '1']
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1928)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:494)

Comment: You should use your Entity property and not the sql column name in jpql

Comment: As you're creating a query and not a native query, make sure your entity bean has a property named GOAL_ID. It looks like a DB column name to me...

Comment: thanks for reply, my problem is solved , yes there was an error in the query,  this worked for me :                                                        Query query1 = em.createQuery("Select e from Exercise e where e.activity = '"+exercise.getActivity()+"' AND e.goal.id= '"+goal.getId()+"'");
                                                                                         List<Exercise> prevexercise=  (List<Exercise>)query1.getResultList();